# Generating Random TimeStamps in Java

Tags: java

I need to generate random numbers starting from 1 to 100 with a repetition factor of 7 in java.
i.e., each number should repeat exactly for 7 times. So, i need to generate 700 numbers in total.

Could anyone please help me how to proceed?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: "each number should repeat exactly for 7 times" --> will make it "non-random"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this

```
    ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        ArrayList list2 = new ArrayList();
        while(list2.size() != 100) {
            int num = rnd.nextInt(101);
            if( num == 0 || list2.contains(num)) {
                continue;
            }
            list2.add(num);
        }
        list1.addAll(list2);
    }
    System.out.println(list1.size());
```

list2 contains subeset of random numbers between 1 to 100 and list1 contains 7 times list2.